# MySQL Hibernate connection issue while using c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I have a web application developed with struts 1.3, Hibernate3 and Spring security. The application was previously dead after 8 hours since MySQL closed the connection after the time. Then i collect the information from several posts to keep it alive for much long now it is almost 20 - 24 hour. Can any body help me out to make this thing working.

**Summary**

Iam unable to login after 20 hours of inactivity. Connection is closed by MySQL.

Thanks.

Please find the below snippets for the configuration of hibernate and c3p0.

**Hibernate cfg file snippet**

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">se.etm.ewo.hibernate.CustomDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">MY_JDBC_URL?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testWhileIdle">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

**Piece of configuration from spring**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <ref bean="hibernateProperties" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>MY_JDBC_URL?autoReconnect=true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>username</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>password</value>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">
        <value>30</value>
    </property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxConnectionAge">
        <value>3600</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">
        <value>3600</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">
        <value>1800</value>
    </property>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts">
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay">
        <value>3000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">
        <value>SELECT 1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**C3p0 log**

> INFO AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:462 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 3, acquireRetryDelay -> 3000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1br9tik951qql1qj1z141xq|2a868f36, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1br9tik951qql1qj1z141xq|2a868f36, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 10, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://url?autoReconnect=true, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 3600, maxIdleTime -> 3600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 1800, maxPoolSize -> 30, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> SELECT 1, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 300, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]

The c3p0 log look exactly these lines , theres nothing related to issue. Can you find anything.

Answer (score 2):

`testWhileIdle` is not a c3p0 property. It doesn't hurt anything, but may confuse you into thinkin you are doing something that you aren't. You are testing idle connections, probably much too frequently, since you are also testing Connections on checkout.

Your config is sprawled across two places. I'm unsure how the Spring and hibernate configs will interact. c3p0 DataSources dump config at INFO on pool init. You might want to verify you have the config you expect.

Re your problem, it sounds very much like you have a Connection leak. You must ensure that any Connection checked out from a DataSource is reliably close()ed in a finally method, or via try-with-resources in Java 7+.

Use c3p0 config params `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` to debug a Connection leak.

See [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

(Note: In hibernate.cfg they'd be `hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`. Or you can set them more directly in your Spring xml.)

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for the reply. I will check this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Could you please check the log i found. I have updated the log at the bottom of question. Please reply if you found anything. The authentication is true but role is anonymous.

Comment: none of the log you've posted is c3p0 related. if you want c3p0's config, it is dumped at INFO on pool init, by a logger called "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource". make sure you are logging all of com.mchange and below at INFO level for ordinary use.

Comment: I read that c3p0 docs according to that it will log in to log4j.  This is what I have in log4j logs. Do we need to configure any logging for c3p0

Comment: it will log to whatever you are logging to... if that's log4j, then it will honor your log4j config.

Comment: Hi I have set another log file specially for c3p0 , Will check that by tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I do get something like the updated one. But all lines look similar except time.

Comment: hi. if i recall, we were just trying to see what config you are running under. you are logging at a DEBUG level, under which c3p0 will generate too much information (including the uninteresting ones you've excerpted above). log at INFO, and look for a message early on, as soon as you start your app. that's when c3p0 will dump its config to log.

Comment: Here's something as you suggested