# C3P0 connection pool gives connection timeout error with this configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, c3p0, connection-timeout

I am using **resin server + spring framework and c3p0 connection pooling.** I have configured the connection pool with the following properties file. But **somehow every 24 hours or so my website faces connection timeout errors and then i have to restart my resin server to make the website live again.** Please tell me whats wrong in the following configuration file and what im missing here.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.databaseURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database1_url
jdbc.StockDatabaseURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database2_url
jdbc.username=my_username
jdbc.password=my_password
jdbc.acquireIncrement=10
jdbc.minPoolSize=20
jdbc.maxPoolSize=30
jdbc.maxStockPoolSize=30
jdbc.maxStatements=100
jdbc.numOfHelperThreads=6
jdbc.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
jdbc.testConnectionOnCheckin=true
jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30
jdbc.prefferedTestQuery=select curdate();
jdbc.maxIdleTime=7200
jdbc.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=5
```

Comment: One reason for the connection timeout could be that all the connections are exhausted. Would you agree if I say that there could be connection leaks in your application? If so, try to identify and fix them. Identifying the leaks can be done easily with c3p0 pooling.

Comment: yes. There are connection leaks but i dont see how that is causing timeout errors.

Comment: I had a similar issue but with different database server. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864383/mysql-hibernate-connection-issue-while-using-c3p0` . Try to enable the logs for c3p0 and check whats going on.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the above configuration.

Comment: I do not believe there is something wrong. If you are able to get even a single connection, then the configuration is mostly correct. If all the connections are exhausted, then the request for new connection has to wait until one is available. Since the connections are not released, the request waiting for connection will timeout.

Comment: How do i check if all connections are exhausted or not?? Using logging???

Comment: I will provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Could to try setting the property `checkoutTimeout` to `30000` (30 secs). Which may give you enough time to create a connection.

Comment: Also i would like to set a point `c3p0` will make you lose lot of time with this issue. I have moved to use `Hikari CP`, then everything seems fine. You can check here http://viswanathl.in/2015/01/configuring-hibernate-and-hikari-cp-in-java-web-application/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, a bunch of things.

- c3p0 has built-in facilities for observing and debugging for Connection leaks. Please set the configuration parameters <strike>unusedConnectionTimeout</strike> [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) and [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces). Set an `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` that defines a period of time after which c3p0 should presume a Connection has leaked, and so close it. Set `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` to ask c3p0 to log the stack trace that checked out the Connection that did not get checked in properly. See [Configuring to Debug and Workaround Broken Client Applications](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).
- You are configuring c3p0 in a nonstandard way. That might be fine, or not, but you want to verify that the config that you intend to set is the config c3p0 gets. c3p0 DataSources dump their config at INFO on pool initialization. *Please consider checking that to be sure you are getting the config you intend.* Alternatively, you can check your DataSource's runtime config via JMX.
- Besides the nonstandard means of configuration, several of your configuration properties seem amiss. `prefferedTestQuery` should be `preferredTestQuery`. `numOfHelperThreads` should be `numHelperThreads`.
- The following are not c3p0 configuration names at all. Perhaps you are internally mapping them to c3p0 configuration, but you'd want to verify this. Here are the not-c3p0-property-names:

  ```
  jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jdbc.databaseURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database1_url
  jdbc.StockDatabaseURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database2_url
  jdbc.username=my_username
  jdbc.maxStockPoolSize=30
  ```

  In a standard c3p0.properties form, what you probably mean is

  ```
  c3p0.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  c3p0.jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database1_url
  # no equivalent -- jdbc.StockDatabaseURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database2_url
  c3p0.user=my_username
  # no equivalent -- jdbc.maxStockPoolSize=30
  ```

  Please see [Configuration Properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties). Again, c3p0 knows nothing about `jdbc.`-prefixed properties, but perhaps something in your own libraries or middleware picks those up.

**Note:** I love to see @NiSay's way of checking for Connection leaks, because I love to see people using more advanced c3p0 API. It will work, as long as you don't hot-update your DataSource's config. But you don't need to go to that much trouble, and there's no guarantee this approach will continue to work in future versions c3p0 makes no promises about ConnectionCustomizer lifecycles. ConnectionCustomizers are intended to be stateless. It is easier and safer to use c3p0's built-in leak check facility, described in the first bullet-point above.

Comment: Yes Steve im internally mapping them to the correct values in the web.xml file. The names that are specified in the jdbc properties file are just variables that are called out in the web.xml file. And i verfied it. preferredTestQuery and numHelperThreads are correct in the web.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I added unusedConnectionTimeout and debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces as you had suggested. And now my website has not dropped since 4 days. But i dont know for how long this will hold my website without dropping. Please tell me if only connection leaks were causing this problem for me? and how to solve connection leaks.

Comment: if Connection leaks were the problem, then setting `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` alone should be sufficient to _workaround_ the problem. (__Note:__  _In my original post and in your reply, I referred to "unusedConnectionTimeout". That was a brainfart. The config param should be `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`. Sorry!_) To _fix_ the problem, also set `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` and then check your log at INFO for the stack traces that opened Connections that later had to be forcibly closed. Then, examine that code and ensure all open Connections are unconditionally closed.

Comment: Once you have fixed the bad code (the code where under some conditions an opened Connection might fail to be closed), unset both config parameters. If you decide that you cannot fix the broken code (maybe it is not under your control), leave `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` set but get rid of `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`, as capturing a stack trace with every Connection checkout exacts a performance toll.

Comment: Sorry its unreturnedConnectionTimeout and debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces. I copy pasted it from your comments but while coding i reffered to the original documentation. Okay thanks alot steve. I will do as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

As there could be possibility of connection leaks in the program (the probable cause of connection timeouts), you need to follow the below steps in order to identify the leaks.

Make as entry in your c3p0.properties file

```
c3p0.connectionCustomizerClassName = some.package.ConnectionLeakDetector
```

Create a class with name 'ConnectionLeakDetector' and place it in appropriate package. Below is the content of the class.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ConnectionLeakDetector implements com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ConnectionCustomizer {

    static AtomicInteger connectionCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    @Override
    public void onAcquire(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken)
            throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckOut(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connections acquired: " + connectionCount.decrementAndGet());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckIn(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connections released: " + connectionCount.incrementAndGet());
    }

}
```

The onCheckOut method will increment the count when the connection is acquired, where as onCheckOut will decrement it when the connection is released.

Execute some scenarios and observe the statistics on your console. If the count is more than 0, then the scenario executed has a connection leak. Try to fix them and you will observe the difference.

As a side note, you can increment the jdbc.maxPoolSize as a temporary solution until you deploy the fix.

Comment: Okay i Will try this solution and post my reply soon.Thanks